# Beaglebone Boot to Qt App

Tags: qt, user-interface, boot, beagleboneblack, systemd

I have searched & googled a lot but I cannot get this to work.

I want the Beaglebone to boot up into my Qt application. However, what I get is that the GUI boots up OK but then in a few seconds the Angstrom login screen overwrites my GUI, which stays running in the background.

I set up a systemd service as follows in /etc/systemd/system:

```
#!/bin/sh

[Unit]
Description=Meta Systemd script
[Service]
USER=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/root
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'source /etc/profile ; /home/root/meta6 -qws'
After=local-fs.target
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I activated it with:

```
systemctl enable meta.service
```

I disabled gdm with:

```
systemctl disable gdm
```

I suspect that maybe I should change the After statement to wait 'til some other service is complete. But what?

Regards,
James

Comment: As I understood you want your application be visible. So, it may try ask X to set it on top (if it is possible within X) or set your `After=` option to the last graphical service. You may even try setting `After=graphical.target` if there is one for graphical bootup.

Comment: Actually, I edited  [link]/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service and commented out ExecStart. This stops the login screen appearing. My app then boots without interruption.

Comment: Uh. Thats a tricky way ;-)

You can try do like set `After=getty@tty1.service` to your apps unit file.

That will make your app run after the tty1 graphical service.

Answer (score 1):

The following commands will disable gdm on Beaglebone Black running angstrom

```
update-rc.d -f gdm remove
systemctl disable gdm.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider removing

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Also add the following to the file

```
[Unit]
After=getty@.service or getty.target
```

Also change the following

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/root/meta6 -qws'
```

The following might not be required

```
[Service] 
After=local-fs.target
```

**Reference**

- [Creating Ångström System Services on BeagleBone Black](http://mattrichardson.com/BeagleBone-System-Services/)